# JFET Constant Current Source (CRD alternative)

Tags: current-source, current-limiting, jfet

Today I have build constant current source based on J111. To drain I connected VCC it's 24VDC from laboratory power supply, then I connected resitor 470Ohm between gate and source. To source pin i connected potentiometer to simulate load (0-1k). Accordingly to simulation in LTSpice I should get around 6mA of current on my load. I connected my multimeter in series (i have also reading from power supply) and current was much higer than I expected. My current source failed. Could someone point me where I have made mistake? I want to create cheaper alternative for CRD.

[image: Constant current source based on J111 in LTSpice]

Comment: Did you measure the threshold voltage and transconductance on the actual device and compare it with the simulation model? These parameters vary quite a lot.

Comment: @BrianDrummond How should I measure that in proper way?

Comment: JFETs have like 100% variation on some of the specifications... So real life will not match the simulation. Try putting a potentiometer in series with a resistor for easy tweaking... Or look for other solutions